# Windows Phone 7 - Playing a specific portion of sound using MediaElement

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I'm trying to play a specific portion of a mp3 file using MediaElement. I understand that I can use the Position property to move to a specific time in the sound and start playing from there. But I would also like to restrict the duration when it plays. For example if a given mp3 file is 30 seconds long, i would specifically like to play the sound from 5th second to 10th second and want the playing to stop.

I thought about using a separate background thread or a timer callback that will measure the time and then wakeup to stop the mediaelement. But I was wondering if the MediaElement itself supports one such a way to specify the duration of the time to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [Markers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.markers%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Once a `Marker` is reached, the [MarkerReached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.markerreached%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event is fired and you can stop the sound `MediaElement` there.